# Error on browser resize after using JQuery in a LWC

Tags: jquery, lightning-web-components, static-resources

I am porting an existing app that uses JQuery to insert HTML into a Lightning Web Component when it is sent a formId via pubsub from another Aura or LW Component. The `sfEnv` object is for sharing data between the FormApp and the LWC and the methods on the `window` are because they are being called from the `FormApp_js`.

Everything works fine with the app including inserting the html. However, if I navigate away from the page or resize my browser window after JQuery and our app bundle resource load (below as `formApp_js`), I get the error pictured below. I'm in a Summer '19 sandbox in Chrome.

What could be causing this?

[image: Error]

Here is the code from the LWC JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { registerListener, unregisterAllListeners } from 'c/pubsub';
import { reduceErrors } from 'c/ldsUtils';
import getQueryThisForm from '@salesforce/apex/Ctl_FormApp.getQueryThisForm';
import queryFormsStr from '@salesforce/apex/Ctl_FormApp.queryFormsStr';
import saveAnswers from '@salesforce/apex/Ctl_FormApp.saveAnswersStr';
import retrieveFieldValues from '@salesforce/apex/Ctl_FormApp.retrieveFieldValuesStr';
import saveDocuments from '@salesforce/apex/Ctl_FormApp.addSFFile';

import jquery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jquery2_0_0';
import jqueryUI from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jqueryUI1_11_2';
import bootstraptransition from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/bootstraptransition';
import bootstrapcollapse from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/bootstrapcollapse';
import bootstrap3 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/bootstrap3';
import moment from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/momentJS';
import jSignature from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jSignature_js';
import formApp from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/formApp_js';

import bootstrap3CSS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/bootstrap3';
import forms_css from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/forms_css';
import SLDS250 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/SLDS250';
import SLDS100 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/SLDS100';

window.namespace = '';
window.sfEnv = {};
sfEnv.thisForm = {};
sfEnv.namespace = '';
sfEnv.SLDS_PATH = '';
sfEnv.orgId = '';
sfEnv.userId = '';
sfEnv.isLWC = true;

export default class FormApp extends LightningElement {
    recordId;

    slds100SpinnerURL = SLDS100+'/assets/images/spinners/slds_spinner_brand.gif'

    @track thisForm;
    @track allForms;
    @track showLoadingBanner;

    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    @wire(getQueryThisForm, { formId: '$recordId' })
    wiredQueryThisForm({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Issue Loading Form',
                    message: reduceErrors(error).join(', '),
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        } else if (data) {           
            window.sfEnv.thisForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

            // If a form is found update allForms value
            if(Object.keys(window.sfEnv.thisForm).length) {
                this.allForms = [window.sfEnv.thisForm];
            }
        }
    }

    @wire(queryFormsStr, { allForms: '$allForms'})
    wiredQueryAllFormsStr({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Issue AllForms',
                    message: reduceErrors(error).join(', '),
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        } else if (data) {
            // loadPageSuccess() is defined in
            if(window.loadPageSuccess !== undefined){
                window.loadPageSuccess(JSON.parse(data),{status:true});
                this.showLoadingBanner = false;
            }
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        registerListener('formSelected', this.handleFormSelected, this);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        unregisterAllListeners(this);
        this.clearExistingForm();
    }

    clearExistingForm(){
        // If a form has already been loaded, clear it out before loading another
        if(window.$formContent && window.$formContent.length === 1 && window.$formContent.find('div').length) {
            window.$formApp.find('.js-pagination-container').empty();
            window.$formApp.off();
            window.$formApp = null;

            window.$formContent.empty();
            window.$formContent.off();
            window.$formContent = null;

            window.$doc = null;

            window.saveAnswersLWC = null;
            window.loadPageSuccess = null;
            window.retrieveFieldValuesLWC = null;
            window.saveDocumentsLWC = null;
        }
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        window.saveAnswersLWC = function(answersToSave,form){
            return saveAnswers({answersToSave, form});
        }
        window.retrieveFieldValuesLWC = function(formulaFieldDatasets){
            return retrieveFieldValues({formulaFieldDatasets});
        }
        window.saveDocumentsLWC = function(docTitle,pathOnClient,externalFileId,answerID,formID,docData){
            return saveDocuments({docTitle,pathOnClient,externalFileId,answerID,formID,docData});
        }

        window.clearExistingForm = this.clearExistingForm;
    }

    handleFormSelected(formId) {
        this.clearExistingForm();

        this.showLoadingBanner = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, jquery),
            loadStyle(this, bootstrap3CSS+'/css/bootstrap.min.css'),
            loadStyle(this, forms_css),
            loadStyle(this, SLDS250+'/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.min.css')
        ])
        .then(() => {
            return Promise.all([
                loadScript(this, jqueryUI+'/jquery-ui.min.js'),
                loadScript(this, bootstraptransition),
                loadScript(this, bootstrapcollapse),
                loadScript(this, bootstrap3+'/js/bootstrap.min.js'),
                loadScript(this, moment),
                loadScript(this, jSignature)
            ]);
        })
        .then(() => {
            if ($(this.template.querySelector('div.form-content')).length) {
                window.$formApp = $(this.template.querySelector('.form-app'));
                window.$formContent = $(this.template.querySelector('div.form-content'));
                window.$doc = this.template;
                return loadScript(this, formApp);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            this.recordId = formId;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            const msg = error && error.body ? error.body.message : JSON.stringify(error);
            alert('resources not loaded: '+msg);
        });
    }
}
```

This HTML File is this:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Form App" class="form-app is-lwc">   
        <main id="panel" class="panel slds-scope">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="mainForm">
                <div class="currentPageContainer">
                    <template if:true={showLoadingBanner}>
                        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture slds-m-top_medium" role="alert" id='loadingMessage'>
                            <div class="slds-spinner_large OR-spinner-align_center">
                                <img src={slds100SpinnerURL} alt="Loading..." />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                    <div id="formContent" class="form-content" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </main>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you checked this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library?

Comment: Yes, that's how I figured out how set up everything in the first place and it generally works fine. I'm just trying to figure out why I get that error on window resize and navigate away.

Comment: Ok, so may I suggest you to add your code on original question?

Comment: @JefersonChaves - Sure, added.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Our `formApp_js` had a `$(window).on('beforeunload',function(){...})` method in it and the `JSignature` library has a `$(window).on('resize',function(){...})` method in it. My temporary fix for the `formApp_js` one was just to but it in a `if(!sfEnv.isLWC) { }` so it runs everywhere expect there. For the JSignature one, I just placed this in the component so I didn't have to modify the library:

```
 if(window.loadPageSuccess !== undefined){
     window.loadPageSuccess(JSON.parse(data),{status:true});
     this.showLoadingBanner = false;
     $(window).off('resize');
 }
```

If decide to re-add those, a proper version will be on `$(this.template)` and not `$(window)`.

Comment: Cool @Rozgonyi, I guess that one lesson I learne is that we should not mess with window variable on LWC.

Comment: Yeah @JefersonChaves. It just gets a little more complicated one you are dealing with a third-party lib like JSignature. I actually ended up modifying the un-minified version so we wouldn't loose that functionality.